# Vue.Js, insert value to element tag

Tags: vue.js

I have the following code:

```
<tr v-for="item in dataset" :key="item[0]" >               
  <td>{{item[1]}}</td>
  <td>
    <input 
      type="checkbox" 
      @change="updateService(item[0])" 
      {{item[2]}}      <--- does not work
    />
  </td>
</tr>
```

`{{item[2]}}` holds the string `"checked"`. How can I insert it into the checkbox element?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to bind the `checked` attribute to be `true` whenever `item[2] === 'checked'`:

```
<input 
  type="checkbox"
  @change="updateService(item[0])"
  :checked="item[2] === 'checked'"
/>
```